# Vuejs and quarkus development and deploy

Tags: java, vue.js, deployment, development-environment, quarkus

I'm a begginer and have a tons os questions, but here is one that I need advice.
I entered in a company that is building a program where the backend is build in Quarkus (java), and the front end in vuejs.
My question is, as microservices, the two projects are done separatadely (diferent servers) with the vue consuming the endpoints of quarkus or they are done together?
Explaining better with an example, in dev mode, one has to run in ex: "localhost:8080" and the other in ex: "localhost:8081"? or the both of them in the same port?

Forgive my english mistakes, thanks a lot.

Comment: It...depends. There are many ways this can play out and really, only your employer can answer this question. Both scenarios are reasonably likely depending on the architecture of the application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is usually three (at least) ways to do this, note that most of them are not Quarkus specific:

1. You deploy your frontend in a webcontainer (httpd, nginx, node) and the Quarkus application separately. You access the Quarkus application via it's URL, for this you'll need CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing) configured.
2. You deploy your frontend in a webcontainer and the Quarkus application separately, but you use the webcontainer to make a proxy to the Quarkus application to avoid having to configure CORS. In this case your frontend will be able to access your backend via localhost on the same port or a relative URL.
3. You package your frontend application inside the Quarkus application (inside `META-INF/resources`) and your frondend access the backend via localhost on the same port or relative URL. The Quarkus application will serve your frontend resoures (HTML, CSS, JS, ...)

Comment: thx man. This was the type of answer I was looking for.

Comment: Wich of these do you recomend? What are the pros and cons of doing these options?

Comment: The right solution is highly dependent of your context. If the same team develop both the frontend and the backend: the easiest is to package the frontend inside the backend. The first solution is the easiest to implements but sometimes you have so much issue to configure the frontend or to enable CORS on the backend that 2 is better.

Answer (score 0):

@loicmathieu shared high level picture. But we will dig even deeper.

Refer this example [Quarkus + Vue.js + MongoDB CRUD Example](https://www.knowledgefactory.net/2021/10/quarkus-vuejs-mongodb-crud-example.html)

Here,

**In development mode**

**Backend** runs on 8081

application.properties

```
quarkus.http.cors=true
quarkus.http.cors.origins=http://localhost:8080
quarkus.http.cors.methods=GET,PUT,POST,DELETE
quarkus.http.port=8081
```

**FrontEnd** runs on 8080

vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        port: 8080
    }
}
```

If you have one team with five folks, or you have multiple teams with n number of folks, or if you alone, no matter

It would be better to implement the Separation of concern principle.
You can concentrate on seperate goals, architecture, speed, etc. Back-end: data processing, front-end: user interaction

Disadvantage

- Need more infrastructure
- Cost